# Google content API for shopping product search from EAN or GTIN

Tags: php, api, google-shopping-api, google-shopping, google-content-api

I am a newbie with Google content API for Shopping . Recently I am working on one project where we do the comparison of products with different competitors.

We have GTIN [ Global Trade Item Number  ] in the database. We would like to perform the search on Google Shopping and get all products with seller brief information.

Searching for a solution for Google Shopping support API for an own merchant account. Google provide API to perform all operation of own feed/products.

I want information shown here http://screencast.com/t/ZYcwn7QpNFA
from Google shopping. Please help me with

Comment: take a look on wordpress plugins with google-shopping. perhaps this will help you to find a fast solution.

Comment: Can you please provide me the URL for plugin?

Comment: did you find any solution @TusharPragma ?

Comment: Not yet. Stil searching for a solution. Google have custom search API but they don't search for google shopping results.

Answer (score 0):

There are many Gtin APi. For example: https://market.mashape.com/mignify/gtin2product. It's very useful for my project. Given a gtin or UPC, this API can return the information about the product, like brand, description.